# How to support Video Codec MPEG-4 file using html tag

Tags: html, video

I have already 3000+ mp4 videos which video codec version is MPEG-4 and does not support any browser. By converting into Codec: MPEG-4 H.264 version it run smoothly. But I can't convert all videos. Is there have any solution to run this video?

```
<video controls preload="none"><source src="_Video_.mp4" type='video/mp4'></video>
```

I have used video and embed html tag but didn't get result. Please help to fix this.

Comment: why can't you convert the videos (ffmpeg is quick and free, you could script it and just let it run). if your source content isn't in a supported format then you'll either have to convert it or use Media Source Extensions to write your own handler

Comment: Have you got any solution yet? I am also facing this problem. This will be great if anyone can post the solution.

Comment: If the browser doesn't support the codec. No there is nothing you can do other than convert.